# Searching in Second column in DataGridView and Giving a yes or no answer

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to figure out how to search from the first Textbox in the second column in the DataGridView and after searching, to list a yes or no answer if the State Abbreviation is a Northwest State in the second Textbox(T2). This is what I have so far.

```
Private Sub L_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Locate.Click
    Dim NW As String = "OR"
    Dim NW2 As String = "WA"
    Dim A As String = T1.Text
    If A = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Must Enter Abbreviation")
    Else
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            If row.Cells.Item("State_Abbreviation").Value = T1.Text Then
                If row.Cells.Item("State_Abbreviation").Value = NW Or NW2 Then
                    T2.Text = "Yes"
                End If
                T2.Text = "No"
            End If
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Valid Abbreviation")
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to simplify your code....

```
Dim result as String = "No"
Dim cellValue = row.Cells.Item("State_Abbreviation").Value.ToString
If cellValue = T1.Text Then
    If cellValue = NW Or cellValue = NW2 Then
       result = "Yes"
    End If
End If
T2.Text = result
```

Comment: I tried adding those simplified versions into my coding, but it is still continuing to have issues

Comment: Nevermind, what you had there helped, the only thing that continued to make errors was the ToString section, which I took out and works perfectly now.